# SQL get the most frequent item for each object

Tags: mysql

```
Table: Food
+------+------+
|Person| Food |
+------+------+
|  A   | Apple|
|  A   | Bread|
|  A   | Bread|
|  A   | Bread|
|  B   |Orange|
|  B   |Orange|
|  B   |Orange|
|  C   |Orange|
|  C   |Orange|
+------+------+
```

How do you find the the most frequent food a person ate and how many times he ate it.
The output would be something like

```
A - Bread - 3
B - Orange - 3
C - Orange - 2
```

I have tried this. But right now the count just gives the amount of food he ate and not the most frequent one.

```
SELECT PERSON,FOOD, COUNT(FOOD)
FROM FOOD
GROUP BY FOOD
ORDER BY COUNT(FOOD)
```

Comment: how do you want ties handled

Comment: all the highest will appear

Comment: separate rows, like `A - Bread - 3` and `A - Orange - 3`?  or together like `A - Bread, Orange - 3`?

Comment: together or seperate would do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working solution:

```
SELECT PERSON, FOOD, MAX(c) FROM  
(SELECT PERSON, FOOD, COUNT(*) AS c  
FROM FOOD  
GROUP BY PERSON, FOOD  
ORDER BY c DESC) AS v  
GROUP BY PERSON;
```

Here is a link to a SqlFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/726798/45

If you want to show the whole list of food counts per person, you can do this:

```
SELECT PERSON, FOOD, COUNT(*) AS C
FROM FOOD
GROUP BY PERSON, FOOD
ORDER BY PERSON, C DESC
```

SqlFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/726798/53

See here [Get top n records for each group of grouped results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12113699/get-top-n-records-for-each-group-of-grouped-results?rq=1) for some more information about finding the arbitrary top *n* most frequent.

Answer (score 0):

You can add rank to your query and make it a subquery to select on that:

```
SELECT PERSON, FOOD, food_count
FROM (
    SELECT PERSON,FOOD,COUNT(FOOD) food_count, DENSE_RANK(COUNT(FOOD)) OVER (PARTITION BY PERSON) food_rank
    FROM FOOD
    GROUP BY PERSON, FOOD
) ranked_counted_foods
WHERE food_rank = 1
```

To select the top three food counts for a person, change to `= 3`.  Then RANK() and DENSE_RANK() will give slightly different behaviors when there are ties.  DENSE_RANK will return 2 even if it returned multiple 1s for ties; RANK will skip numbers when there are ties.